# row_number function returns empty string rows first but not in the order they are in the table

Tags: sql-server-2008, row-number

I have a table with one column item from items table

it has some 20 reocords, where some rows have empty strings but not null values

So when  i use row_number() function on table like this

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over( order by item asc) as row,item  from items
```

it is returning rows which contains empty strings as first and then other rows next, but not in the order they are in the table.

I heard that row_number () will generates a sequential number for the rows in the same order as they are retrieved from table.

i want to retrieve records with row_number in the same order how they are in the table even though row contains empty string not null,

how is this possible

Answer (score 1):

ROW_NUMBER always requires an ORDER BY clause.So it is not possible to retrieve the records with same order as in the table using ROW_NUMBER function.